# Position Text after Background Image (background-size:cover)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place my website header as a full background image, but still allow the user to scroll down into the next section of the website. I am using body background-image to prevent any white frame/margin around the image, but need to place content after (and on top of) the image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>Olivia E Thorne</h1>
    <p>Brighton, UK</p>
</header>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    background:url('header.png') #A98436 no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

header{
    position: fixed;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 50%;
    top: 35%;
    left: 45%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I have not included the header on the image as I will eventually be animating it, so it needs to be able to be positioned on top of the image. I also need to prevent any white 'frames' around the image (so placing it into the HTML directly has not worked).

Comment: Remove the background-attachment:fixed; from your css. This will allow the user to scroll down away from the image.

Comment: Hi, I have just done that but still can't scroll down from the image even when adding content that should, in theory, be further down.

Comment: So you will have to position the next element below the header image. So set position:relative; and the  "top:" property of that element to the height of the image for the following element. I give you an answer with code.

Comment: Fantastic that worked! If you post it as an answer I will mark as answered.

Comment: Awesome, I just posted the answer! Happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header>
<h1>Olivia E Thorne</h1>
<p>Brighton, UK</p>
</header>
<div class="next"> <p>Some content...</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
background:url('header.png') #A98436 no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

header{
position: fixed;
color: whitesmoke;
font-family: "Segoe UI";
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 50%;
top: 35%;
left: 45%;
z-index: 100;
} 
.next{
position:relative;
top: 500px; (or 50% or whatever the height of the pic is)
}
```